# Using p5.sound.js in instance mode: 'p5.Amplitude() not a constructor'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, processing, processing.js, p5.js

I am using an npm, webpack, babel environment to write an application with p5.js. To be able to have the sketch as a module, I have the sketch in [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Instantiation-Cases) and import the library and add-ons as modules:

```
import p5 from 'p5';
import 'p5/lib/addons/p5.sound';
import 'p5/lib/addons/p5.dom';
```

Then I load them to the window inside my sketch:

```
const sketch = (p5) => {
   window.p5 = p5;
   ...
}
new p5(sketch);
```

When I try to use:

```
amp = new p5.Amplitude()
```

I get a 'p5.Amplitude is not a constructor' error. My prediction is that there is a conflict between naming the library p5 on the window and using the constructors from the library that use p5.something like p5.Amplitude, p5.Vector, p5.Soundfile. I have not been able to find a workaround to using these objects or constructors within instance mode. I am however able to use the methods from these [objects](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/) that do not require a constructor. For example, `loadSound()` is a method of p5.Soundfile. The following works:

`sound = p5.loadSound('assets/sound.wav)`

but when I try `console.log(p5.SoundFile)` I get undefined.

I am lost!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a JavaScript expert, but your syntax doesn't match the syntax on the [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Instantiation-Cases) page.

Specifically, what are you doing here?

```
const sketch = (p5) => {
   window.p5 = p5;
   ...
}
new p5(sketch);
```

Compare that to the syntax on the instance mode page:

```
var sketch = function (p) {
  var gray = 0; 

  p.setup = function () {
    p.createCanvas(600, 400);
  };

  p.draw = function () {
    p.background(gray);
    p.rect(p.width/2, p.height/2, 200, 200);
  };

  p.mousePressed = function () {
    gray = (gray + 16) % 256;
  };
};

new p5(sketch);
```

It looks like your code is redefining the `p5` variable, which is going to cause the kinds of problems you're seeing. I would rewrite your code to no longer redefine the `p5` variable, and use the syntax from the instance mode page instead:

```
var sketch = function(p) {
   //your code here
   //but don't change the p5 variable!
}
new p5(sketch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Kevin. I use `window.p5 = p5` to be able to load the library using es6 modules. With the latter I am making the library available in the window after using `import p5 from '....'`. I am able to use the rest of the functionality just like instance mode using p5 instead of p. Def not a javascript expert either, but I based this decision based on [this](https://github.com/vogelino/molecular-networks-p5-algorithm/blob/master/src/js/index.js) project which seems to pull it off smoothly. Cheers!

Comment: I struggled for hours trying to get p5.js to work with es6 module syntax, until I found your answer, Kevin.  Works great!

Comment: I raised a similar issue here that follows a similar solution like what you proposed here... stackoverflow.com/questions/64887033/… I'm able to get function calls like .loadSound() to work but not constructor eg: .Envelope() do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you're overwriting the `p5` **class** provided by the library with the **instance** that's provided to your code upon construction.

This should work:

```
import p5 from 'p5';
import 'p5/lib/addons/p5.sound';

const sketch = (p5) => {
   window.myp5 = p5;

   p5.setup = () => {
     //whatever
   };

   p5.draw = draw;
}

function draw() {
  //methods hang off the instance:
  const mysound = myp5.loadSound("/path/to/sound.mp3");
  //constructors hang off the class:
  const amp = new p5.Amplitude()
}
new p5(sketch);
```

Note that `myp5` is available to the draw function because of the assignment at the beginning of the `sketch` function. Also note that you shouldn't need to import the addons.

Comment: I raised a similar issue here that follows a similar solution like what you proposed here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887033/how-do-i-add-p5-sound-to-react-using-react-p5-wrapper/64888427#64888427

I'm able to get function calls like .loadSound() to work but not constructor eg: .Envelope() do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out our problems. You need to use p5.sound library from version 0.9.0 and place it in your project's directory. I explain more fully in my answer here:

[How to import and utilize P5.Sound in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61985249/how-to-import-and-utilize-p5-sound-in-vue/61989890#61989890)