# How do I add p5.sound to React using react-p5-wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js, ml5.js

I'm trying to get figure how I can include p5.sound to my p5 Sketch.
Currently I'm using react-p5-wrapper https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper/ to get p5 into React.

There's a similar issue raised in the repo and I've asked the same question there too, https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper/issues/11#issuecomment-728986112 but I can't quite figure out the steps they recommended to solve the problem.

I've added `import * as p5 from "p5"` and `import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound"` in my Sketch file but it isn't working. I got the error as per the screenshot.

I'm just trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HEgeAbYphA&feature=emb_logo but try to do it in React.

```
import * as React from "react"
import * as p5 from "p5"
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound"
import * as ml5 from "ml5"

export default function sketch(p5) {
    p5.setup = () => {
        p5.createCanvas(400, 400)

        env = new p5.Envelope()
        env.setADSR(0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1)
        env.setRange(1.2, 0)

        wave = new p5.Oscillator()
        wave.setType("sine")
        wave.start()
        wave.freq(440)
        wave.amp(env)
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with p5 in a while, but I suspect you're having the same problem as I solved in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44727829/1712343) you commented on. In your workaround answer, you have two different objects with the same name, `p5`, with the effect that `window.p5` (the p5 **class**) is shadowed by the argument to the `sketch` function of the same name (the p5 **instance**). You need access to both.

There's a convention that classes start with a capital letter, so I'd try this first:

```
import * as ml5 from "ml5"
import * as P5 from "p5"
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound"

export default function sketch(p5) {
    p5.setup = () => {
        p5.createCanvas(400, 400)
        //methods hang off the instance:
        song = p5.loadSound(url("./assets/hurry.mp3"))
        //constructors hang off the class:
        env = new P5.Envelope()
```

If you find the distinction between `P5` and `p5` confusing, you can name the class anything else besides `p5`, like:

```
import * as p5Class from 'p5'
...
export default function sketch(p5) {
    p5.setup = () => {
        p5.createCanvas(400, 400)
        //methods hang off the instance:
        song = p5.loadSound(url("./assets/hurry.mp3"))
        //constructors hang off the class:
        env = new p5Class.Envelope()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that only works on function calls.
I added window.p5 = p5 after calling import * as p5 from "p5"

```
import * as ml5 from "ml5"
window.p5 = p5
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound"
```

Then I'll be able to use the p5.loadSound() function. However if I try to use new p5.Envelope() constructor it'll still throw me an error.

```
export default function sketch(p5) {
    p5.setup = () => {
        p5.createCanvas(400, 400)
        song = p5.loadSound(url("./assets/hurry.mp3")) // Will work
        env = new p5.Envelope() // Will error
...
```

**Update:** Ah just changing `p5.Envelope() --> p5.constructor.Envelope()` fixes the problem!

Comment: ml5? It's impossible! Absolutely, the browser will always say that 'p5' is not defined